# Get the full path of the files in C

Tags: c, path

Basically this piece of code gives me names of the files in the directory....But I need to get their paths instead.. I tried to use function realpath(). But I am using it wrong I guess(I showed in code where i wanted to use it). Any ideas how to fix it?. One more thing: It gives me only names of subdirectories, but basically I need to get paths of the their files too.Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int c, char *v[]) {
    int len, n;
    struct dirent *pDirent;
    DIR *pDir;
    int ecode=0;
    struct stat dbuf;
    for (n=1; n<c; n++){
        if (lstat(v[n], &dbuf) == -1){
            perror (v[n]);
            ecode ++;
        }
        else if(S_ISDIR(dbuf.st_mode)){
            printf("%s is a directory/n ", v[n]);
        }
        else{
            printf("%s is not a directory\n", v[n]);
        }
    }
    if (c < 2) {
        printf ("Usage: testprog <dirname>\n");
        return 1;
    }
    pDir = opendir (v[1]);
    if (pDir == NULL) {
        printf ("Cannot open directory '%s'\n", v[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while ((pDirent = readdir(pDir)) != NULL) {
        // here I tried to use realpath()
        printf ("[%s]\n", realpath(pDirent->d_name));
    }
    closedir (pDir);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `realpath` should work, what are you seeing and what do you expect?

Comment: I think I am using it wrong there...Can I say like realpath(pDirent->d_name) as I used in code??? I think no...I added char actualpath [PATH_MAX]; And then tried like printf ("[%s]\n", realpath(actualpath,pDirent->d_name)); But it still does not work....

Comment: My man realpath says this: `char *realpath(const char *restrict file_name, char *restrict resolved_name);`.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to add the second argument to realpath, because it needs a buffer to write into. I recommend you take the line out of the printf statement and give it its own line. realpath() *can* return a char*, but it wasn't designed to.

```
#include <limits.h>       //For PATH_MAX

char buf[PATH_MAX + 1]; 
while ((pDirent = readdir(pDir)) != NULL) {
    realpath(pDirent->d_name, buf);
    printf ("[%s]\n", buf);
}
```

This appears to display the full paths properly on my system.

Comment: Does `realpath` work like this if you aren't `cwd`'d into the directory containing those files?