# How to get the file path of a file in c(how to do this in windows)

Tags: c

I need to get the file path of a file i recently created in c

```
FILE *pFile;
pFile=fopen("client.txt","w");//create and open file in write mode
```

now how can i get the file path of client.txt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Linux, how can I get the filename from the "struct file" structure, while stepping thru the kernel with kgdb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885676/in-linux-how-can-i-get-the-filename-from-the-struct-file-structure-while-ste)

Comment: The current directory is `.`. and you can use `getcwd` as documented in [answer] [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298510/how-to-get-the-current-directory-in-a-c-program]

Comment: Also possible duplicate of [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19641798/get-the-full-path-of-the-files-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the current working directory. [getcwd](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd) will do this for you.

This should work

```
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <linux/limits.h>

 char path[MAX_PATH + 1];
 char *cwd = getcwd(path, MAX_PATH);
```

Comment: how to do this in windows ?

Comment: Can you not even click on the linked question in this very answer?